# How to use @Valid annotation on return type of a internal method

Tags: java, annotations

I have a REST API, inside which I'm transforming the request passed. Now I want to validate the entity which was transformed using @Valid annotation.

```
public RequestResponse create(EntityV1 entityV1){
    Entity entity = transform(entityV1)
}

private Entity transform(EntityV1 entityV1){
    Entity entity = new Entity();
    //Transformation logic
    return entity;
}
```

Please suggest me a way through which the return type of transform can be validated using my custom annotation.

Constraint:
I cannot change the Input of my rest api from EntityV1 to Entity

Answer (score 0):

You will need to programmatically validate the bean as follows:

```java
@Autowired
Validator validator;

public RequestResponse create(EntityV1 entityV1, BindingResult bindingResult){
    Entity entity = transform(entityV1);

    validator.validate(entity, bindingResult);
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        // validation errors
    } else {
        // no errors
    }
}
```